# How to store a value in database using user's input in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

```
class User(models.Model):
    GENDER = [
        ('0', 'Male'),
        ('1', 'Female'),
    ]
    DEGREE = [
        ('0', 'High School or below'),
        ('1', 'Associate or Bachelor'),
        ('2', 'Master or PhD'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = GENDER, null=True)
    age = model.IntegerField(null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = DEGREE, null=True)
```

Assuming I have a formula that calculate credit scores based on this input, for example, 2.03884 * ln(age) + 12.8938 * ln(degree) + 9.9 * (ln(degree)^2).

Now, I am just curious about where, how and what should I do so that whenever I look up at the User, I can obtain his/her/their score? Thank you very much for spending your time to help me since I am extremely new to Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed property:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # model fields
    
    @property
    def credit_scores(self):
        return self.age * 2  # replace with your custom logic
```

Using:

```
user = User.objects.first()
print(user.credit_scores)
```